# Calculating index from sentinel-2 in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I am trying to calculate a water index from Sentinel 2 dataset from Sentinel 2, the error is 'Error: reduce.median: Error in map(ID=20180101T041721_20180101T041718_T47SND): Image.select: Pattern 'nd' did not match any bands.' I'm not clear what 'nd' means? How to export the index value from the image collection (S2)?

Here's my code,

```
// Function to calculate and add an AWEInsh band
var addAWEInsh = function(image) {
return image.addBands(image.expression(
    '4*(GREEN - SWIR1)-(0.25*NIR+2.75*SWIR2)', {
      'GREEN': image.select('B3'),
      'SWIR1': image.select('B11'),
      'SWIR2': image.select('B12'),
      'NIR': image.select('B8'),
}));
};

// Add NDWI band to image collection
var S2 = S2.map(addAWEInsh);
// Extract NDWI band and creat NDWI median composite image
var AWEInsh = S2.select(['nd']);
var AWEInsh = AWEInsh.median();
```

Comment: Could you please add the line where you define S2 so we can test your code fully? Also how can you not know what 'nd' means if you wrote yourself the command '.select(['nd'])'?

Comment: The OP doesn't know because the code was written by someone else https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/9/12/1315/s1

Answer (score 4):

`S2.select(['nd'])` is asking for the band named `'nd'` in each image in the collection. It only makes sense if you *have* a band named `'nd'`. There's nothing special about that particular name.

It sounds like a reasonable name for your band is `AWEInsh`, so you'd do that like this:

```js
var addAWEInsh = function(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.expression(
      'AWEInsh = 4*(GREEN - SWIR1)-(0.25*NIR+2.75*SWIR2)', {  // Changed expression
        'GREEN': image.select('B3'),
        'SWIR1': image.select('B11'),
        'SWIR2': image.select('B12'),
        'NIR': image.select('B8'),
  }));
};

var S2 = S2.map(addAWEInsh);
var AWEInsh = S2.select(['AWEInsi']);                         // Changed select()
var AWEInsh = AWEInsh.median();
```

Note that I added `AWEInsh =`  to your image `expression`. That's a way to set the band name inside an expression. You can also use `.rename()` if you have an image with a band that you didn't use `expression()` to create.

Or, in your particular case, if you just need a median and aren't doing *more* work, then it can simpler to just work with one-band images and not worry about the name:

```js
var computeAWEInsh = function(image) {
  return image.expression(                                    // Removed addBands
      '4*(GREEN - SWIR1)-(0.25*NIR+2.75*SWIR2)', {
        'GREEN': image.select('B3'),
        'SWIR1': image.select('B11'),
        'SWIR2': image.select('B12'),
        'NIR': image.select('B8'),
  }));
};

var AWEInsh = S2.map(computeAWEInsh).median();
```

The result will have only one band, which means you don't necessarily need to worry about what it's named (or if the name does end up mattering, you can `.rename('AWEInsh')`).

Comment: It works. Thank you very much! ^^